# CANopen Interface

Tags: ros, can

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there!!

I'm new on ROS and I'm trying to move a motor that have a CANopen (Control Area Network) interface. Looking into the stack list I'd find the cob_canopen_motor. Well, the problem is that I don't know how to make it work. There is not a "cob_canopen_motor_node" to run and there isn't any documentation.

I'm trying hard! :D

well, thanks a lot!!

Jeferson

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9966/canopen-interface/) by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 482 on 2011-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> There is not a "cob_canopen_motor_node" to run

That is correct. If you look at the `CMakeLists.txt`, you can see that it only compiles a shared library. Which means that this library will be used somewhere.

> and there isn't any documentation

Actually, there is some documentation about cob_canopen_motor on its [ros wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cob_canopen_motor). If you click on "Used By", you can see that e.g. [cob_base_drive_chain](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cob_base_drive_chain) uses this package, so I would suggest to look there on how to use it.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-05-17**:
Ow yes you are right about the documentation, but it talks about the cob plataform (off course it's a cob driver! hehe). The question is: "How can I use only the specific drive that commands the CAN layer?" tks again